# Which one action in actionlist is IDE keymap : "Show context action"

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

I want to binding "Show context action" in `.ideavimrc` but I can't find this action in actionlist.

The action names are little different in Keymap and actionlist.

In the Keymap:

[image]

Comment: My best guess right now: assign an additional shortcut to that action in your Keymap, exit IDE and check IDE config files -- then one for keymap. It will have an action name there. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Tuning_the_IDE.html#config-directory **P.S.** If IDE is installed using JetBrains Toolbox App then the path to config might be different -- in such case you may need to see `idea.log` file for details (it should be mentioned at the start of the session).

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks you!! I found the keymaps setting file. and there have real action name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to get the real action name.
for example, if I want to add the action "Show context actions" that called this name in keymaps.
I would add another shortcut in this keymaps, and go to the keymaps folder to get setting file. In the setting file there has real action name.

Comment: What would be the action name you found out?

Comment: "Show context actions" => "ShowIntentionActions"